# undefined reference to `_gmtime32' with boost threads tutorial

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, mingw, boost-thread

I was following this beginner tutorial on boost threads:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/279053/How-to-get-started-using-Boost-threads

Everything was going fine with this sample they provided:

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

void workerFunc()
{
    boost::posix_time::seconds workTime(3);
    std::cout << "Worker: running" << std::endl;

    // Pretend to do something useful...
    boost::this_thread::sleep(workTime);
    std::cout << "Worker: finished" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "main: startup" << std::endl;
    boost::thread workerThread(workerFunc);

    std::cout << "main: waiting for thread" << std::endl;
    workerThread.join();

    std::cout << "main: done" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But then I decided to try it without the sleep function. So I commented out those lines.

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

void workerFunc()
{
    //boost::posix_time::seconds workTime(3);
    std::cout << "Worker: running" << std::endl;

    // Pretend to do something useful...
    //boost::this_thread::sleep(workTime);
    std::cout << "Worker: finished" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "main: startup" << std::endl;
    boost::thread workerThread(workerFunc);

    std::cout << "main: waiting for thread" << std::endl;
    workerThread.join();

    std::cout << "main: done" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I started to get the following compile error:

> )]+0x40)||undefined reference to `_gmtime32'|

I've done quite a bit of snooping around trying to figure out what this means and why it is only happening when I remove those two lines. As of right now, I am leaning towards it being something to do with some kind of header, like time.h, that I have to include (although I tried that already obviously).

I am using a rather strange setup. Code::Blocks with mingw/gcc. I compiled the boost library myself with command line arguments following the codeblocks tutorial: 
http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=BoostWindowsQuickRef

Everything seemed to work fine with this, but I suppose I could have built the libraries incorrectly.

I would dig deeper but the file name of the error is not standard and is listed as ")]+0x40)". I am not sure what this means - is it maybe some kind of file location address?

**MORE INFO:**

```
Windows XP 32 bit
CodeBlocks 10.05
MingW GCC 4.4.3
Boost 1_53_0
```

BUILD LOG:

> Linking console executable: bin\Debug\Bjarne_Strousup_Samples.exe
>   ....\CodeBlocks\lib\libboost_thread-mgw44-mt-1_53.a(thread.o):thread.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9date_time6c_time6gmtimeEPKlP2tm[boost::date_time::c_time::gmtime(long
>   const*, tm*)]+0x40): undefined reference to `_gmtime32' collect2: ld
>   returned 1 exit status Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 6
>   seconds) 1 errors, 0 warnings

COMMAND LINE ATTEMPT:

```
C:\CodeBlocks Tests\BoostExamples>g++ main.cpp -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lb
oost_chrono
main.cpp:5:28: error: boost/thread.hpp: No such file or directory
main.cpp:6:31: error: boost/date_time.hpp: No such file or directory
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:21: error: 'boost' has not been declared
main.cpp:21: error: expected ';' before 'workerThread'
main.cpp:24: error: 'workerThread' was not declared in this scope

C:\CodeBlocks Tests\BoostExamples>
```

LINKER SETTINGS:
[image: Linker Settings]

IDM Link:
[http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.basetechref%2Fdoc%2Fbasetrf1%2Fctime.htm](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.basetechref/doc/basetrf1/ctime.htm)

I think the error is on this line of c_time.hpp:

```
  static std::tm* gmtime(const std::time_t* t, std::tm* result)
```

Comment: I have no problem compiling and linking either of you examples with MinGW 4.7.2 and Boost 1.51 with the following command line: `g++ test.cpp -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lboost_chrono` (there's no `I option for boost because the boost headers have been added to the MinGW include directory so they're available implicitly). What versions of MinGW and Boost are you using?

Comment: And the `)]+0x40)||undefined reference to '_gmtime32'` error message is just a fragment of the full error. I assume that your IDE has clipped the bulk of the error message (due to line wrap?).  You should look in the log file (hopefully it's easy to locate and/or convince the IDE to generate) for the full error.  Knowing which module contains the reference to `_gmtime32()` might help point the way to the right solution.

Comment: Also, post the command line used to compile and link the program.  The order that libraries are specified on the command line is significant (with the GNU linker), and that's probably why removing function calls results in the linker error. One of those function calls pulled in the `_gmtime32()` wrapper.  But I think that whatever refers to `_gmtime32()` in your second example is in a library that's listed 'too late' in the list of libraries being searched by the linker.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I am not great with command lines. I've just been compiling it with Code::Blocks. But I posted my probably poorly executed attempt at using the command line. -- I also posted my linker settings in codeblocks. I've tried several different orderings of the library files in here, some orderings seem to cause other problems - so maybe there is a "correct" combination for these libraries in the linker settings. I also was able to generate the full build log - see above. The full error provides more information. It seems to be a problem in the thread library file- but I am not sure how.

Comment: @MichaelBurr - I think I found the line in the library source files where the error is occuring. I did some more research on gmtime() and I found this warning from IBM: "Attention: Do not use the ctime, localtime, gmtime, or asctime subroutine in a multithreaded environment. See the multithread alternatives in the ctime_r (ctime_r, localtime_r, gmtime_r, or asctime_r Subroutine), localtime_r, gmtime_r, or asctime_r subroutine article."-link above. I also found a comment around this line implying they tried to use gmtime_r() but had a problem: "// gmtime_r() not in namespace std???"

Comment: @MichaelBurr - I think I might be somewhat shooting in the dark at this point.

Comment: I think some analysis along with some guesswork and a little trial and error is what may people would end up doing. One potential issue with the list of link libraries is that you have both release and debug boost libraries in the list.  I think that you need ot have separate build configurations, one for release builds (with only the boost release libraries) and a debug configuration (with only the debug libraries).

Comment: Another possible problem is you have the thread lib near the end of the list of libs. `boost_thread` depends on system, chrono and date_time (see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/build.html), though the dependencies might be header only (data_time) or configurable (chrono). Regardless, I think it's best to put `boost_thread` at the list start so that it can pick up dependencies from the other other libraries as needed (none of the other libs depend on thread). That's the way the GNU linker works - libs that provide dependencies must be after the libs that depend on them.

Comment: Also, the IBM warning about `gmtime()` and thread safety isn't an issue with the `msvcrt.dll` runtime that MinGW uses for its core runtime. `msvcrt.dll` provides a per-thread instance of `struct tm` for `gmtime()` to return a pointer to.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I am going to call the sleep function for 0 seconds at the beginning of the program. Looks like it only needs to be called once. I've tried all the combinations for linking the libraries. No success. This should be a good enough workaround for my purposes.

Comment: Maybe one day I'll look into it more but I have a strong feeling it is something specific to my setup that is unusual.